# How to write music theory symbols in Evernote?

Tags: fonts, music, evernote, font-faces

I want type my music theory class notes in Evernote but I can’t seem to figure out how to do this correctly. I have managed to put following symbols in Evernote just by copy and pasting but some as you can see are missing including clefs, ideally I would like to type these:

- o whole note
- ? half note
- ♩ quarter note
- ♪ eighth note
- ♫ single bar note (2 eight note)
- ♬ double bar note
- ♭ flat note
- ♮ natural note
- ♯ sharp note
- ? clefs

Answer (score 1):

You can find a full list of Unicode music symbols, as well as scalable vector graphics to copy and paste, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Music).